# Proguard directives for Twilio Client library

Tags: android, proguard, twilio

What is the recommended proguard directives (exclusions) when running the Twilio Client for Android (i.e. including the jar and .so files?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following directives works well when using the proguard-android-optimize.txt:

```
-keep class com.twilio.** { *; }
```

Comment: You shouldn't specify the -libraryjars option, since the Android build process already does that for you. With the option, you'll see lots of notes about duplicate classes.

Comment: @EricLafortune THanks Eric. edited the answer. So - do I know need to remove all of my -libraryjars from all of my project's proguard files? e.g. is it obsolete when using the new android "default" proguard files?

Comment: The standard Android Ant/Eclipse/Gradle build processes specify all the necessary -injars/-libraryjars/-outjars for you; you shouldn't repeat them yourself. This is true for all old and new versions of the Android SDK.